# URL character issue

Tags: swift, url, swift3, character

I have issue with url's character and this is my code ;

my function ;

```
func getMahalle (addres: String){

    let urlString = adres
    let url = URL(string: urlString)// I'm getting error right after this line when have urlString ı,İ,ş,Ş,ü,Ü,ç,Ç,ğ,Ğ,ö,Ç , url = nil after this line

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data,urlresponse, error) in
        if error != nil {

            print(error!)

        }

        else {

            do {

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                if let table = json["Table"] {

                    for var i in 0..<(table as AnyObject).count {

                        let tableDict = (table as! Array<AnyObject>) [i] as! [String: Any]

                        let iller = tableDict["site_mahalle"]
                        self.mahallelerDizi.append(iller as! String)

                                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch {

            }

        }

    }
    task.resume() }
```

call ;

```
getMahalle(addres: "http://alfa.reelim.com/ReelService.asmx/getMahalle?ilce=nilüfer")
```

error is : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I m not understand why url = nil.

Comment: Can you please show the code where from you calling the function func getMahalle (addres: String) and how?

Comment: Misspelling: `let urlString = adres` but it wouldn't have compiled.

Comment: But i don't have a compile issue

Comment: I realize that, so it probably happened when you pasted the code in here. I was just pointing it out, not as a solution to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Adding percent encoding](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1411946-addingpercentencoding) should do the job:

```
let urlString = adres.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlFragmentAllowed)
let url = URL(string: urlString!) // Take care of forced wrapping

// Here this url: http://alfa.reelim.com/ReelService.asmx/getMahalle?ilce=Ö
// will become this: http://alfa.reelim.com/ReelService.asmx/getMahalle?ilce=%C3%96
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) // Take care of forced wrapping
{ 
   (data,urlresponse, error) in

    // parsing here
}
```

A part from doc:

> **Important** 
>   You must not call this method on strings that are already
>   percent-encoded. *Calling this method on strings that are already
>   percent-encoded will cause percent characters in a percent-encoded
>   sequence to be percent-encoded twice.*

and:

> **Return Value** Returns the encoded string, *or nil if the transformation
>   is not possible*.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


let secilenIlce = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "secilenIlce") as? NSString
    if let yansiyan = secilenIlce {

        degerMahalle = yansiyan as String
    } mahalleCek(adres: "http://alfa.reelim.com/ReelService.asmx/getMahalle?ilce=\(degerMahalle)")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape unsupported characters:

```
guard let escaped = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed),
      let url = URL(string: escaped)
    else {
        fatalError("Better handle the error")
}
```

Comment: I implemented and url: "http:%2F%2Falfa.reelim.com%2FReelService.asmx% getMahalle%3 ilce=Optional(%22nilüfer%22)"

Comment: @learning, unwrap `degerMahalle` variable like you posted in your above answer `/getMahalle?ilce=\(degerMahalle!)")}` // Notice the `!` sign.

Comment: I did but now "http:%2F%2Falfa.reelim.com%2FReelService.asmx% getMahalle%3 ilce=nilüfer" still url = nil

Comment: Please post the unprocessed URL.

Comment: "nilüfer"  is not escaped (ü). MAybe escape only the parameters. (nilüfer)